# How to prevent that print changes image resolution?

Tags: matlab, printing

I tries to create a text image (i think it is called that way) in matlab. That means that I want to create an image containing text. The problem is that there is no matlab function that can do this. The solution is that I use `text` and then captures the output in the figure.

In the beginning I used `getframe` to capture the output. This went completely fine as long as I did not do anything else on the screen at the same time. The problem is that |getframe| captures whatever is on the screen at the moment, which have led to annoying bugs. In hope of solving this problem I plan to use |print| instead. However, now I have the problem of image resolution changes when print is used. Do anyone know a solution for this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
xlen = 1200; ylen = 700;
im = uint8(255*ones(ylen,xlen,3));
hf = figure('color','white','units','normalized','position',[.1 .1 .8 .8]);
image(ones(size(im)));
set(gca,'units','pixels','position',[5 5 size(im,2)-1 size(im,1)-1],'visible','off')
text('units','pixels','position',[1 ylen/2],'fontsize',60,'FontWeight','Bold','string','This is text')
set(hf,'Units','pixels')
set(hf,'Position',[100,100,xlen,ylen],'paperpositionmode','auto');
print(hf, '-dpng', 'myText.png');
```

Comment: you can set the resolution by `print(hf, '-dpng','-d600', 'myText.png');` (600dpi) - and apart from that: why not vector graphics?

Comment: @thewaywewalk The image will not be used in matlab. Also the image need to be cut since the text may be of different length (and different number of rows). `text` is only defined in a point and with a font size. That means I need to capture the screen to be able to cut out the text part.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I guess that you mean `'-r600'` and I am afraid it did not work out as expected. The image got huge.

Comment: you need to set `'Paperposition'` or `'Papersize'` somewhere, and do that in e.g. centimeters and not in pixels. Otherwise it assumes one pixel of the picture would be one pixel on the screen, and it gets huge, yes.

Comment: @thewaywewalk the `'PaperPosition'` is set in inches, but changein to centimeters does not change the size. However, matlab themselves proudly states in the [help](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/print.html#f30-443541) that setting `'PaperPositionMode'` to `'auto'` will override the `'PaperPosition'` property. It does however not seem like that.

Comment: Not really, that I care about the rep that much, but please who downvotes without a comment. IMO the problem is clear and can be reproduced with a short, concise, easy to read example.

Comment: actually you earn +1 for the minimal running example ;) -> +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have finally found a solution. Matlab uses 150 dpi resolution by default. This is kind of weird since windows use 96 dpi resolution in their operating system and mac uses 72 dpi. However, what I have heard it is recommended to use at least 150 dpi on printed material to get good quality. Anyway, since windows uses 96 dpi, it is clear that you need to set the image resolution to 96 dpi as well to `print` (refering to matlabs function `print`) a figure with the right size.

```
xlen = 1200; ylen = 700;
im = uint8(255*ones(ylen,xlen,3));
hf = figure('color','white','units','normalized','position',[.1 .1 .8 .8]);
image(ones(size(im)));
set(gca,'units','pixels','position',[5 5 size(im,2)-1 size(im,1)-1],'visible','off')
text('units','pixels','position',[1 ylen/2],'fontsize',60,'FontWeight','Bold','string','This is text')
set(hf,'Units','pixels')
set(hf,'Position',[100,100,xlen,ylen],'paperpositionmode','auto');
print(hf, '-dpng', '-r96','myText.png'); % SET RESOLUTION TO '-r96' for windows.
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving images in matlab can be a real struggle.
I found my solution by using export_fig from the mathlab file exchange (see
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig).

Some of the aims of export fig are:

- Figure/axes reproduced as it appears on screen
- Cropped borders (optional)
- Embedded fonts (pdf only)

Comment: I try to avoid 3:rd party libraries in general. If no other solution is found I will go for `getframe`, but if possible I would like to do it another way.